# Date & if else statement PHP

Tags: php, date, time

I am working on some PHP code currently that seems to work logically

```
$tod = date("G");
if($tod >= 5 && $tod <= 11)      { $work = "Morning's"; }
elseif($tod >= 12 && $tod <= 17) { $work = "Afternoon's"; }
else                               $work = "Evening's";

$dw = date( "l");

if($work = "Morning's")       { $pre = "Morning"; }
elseif($work = "Afternoon's") { $pre = "Afternoon"; }
else                            $pre = "Evening";
```

For some reason if I try to increase or set the $tod variable to something in each range when I echo $work it always returns "Morning's" no matter what $tod is set to. Is something wrong with my if..elseif..else statements? I'm not getting any errors when I load the page.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Just as an aside, why do you use two `if` blocks here? Why not assign `$pre` at the same time as `$work`? Also, take the `'`s out ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this you have forget  "=" in two if

```
  $tod = date("G");
    if($tod >= 5 && $tod <= 11) {$work = "Morning's";}
    elseif($tod >= 12 && $tod <= 17) {$work = "Afternoon's";}
    else $work = "Evening's";
    $dw = date( "l");
    if($work == "Morning's"){$pre = "Morning";}
    elseif($work == "Afternoon's"){$pre = "Afternoon";}
    else $pre = "Evening";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to shorten that a litte (and correct the spelling: Plural is w/o `'`):

```
$pre = "Evening";
in_array( date( "G" ), range( 5, 11 ) )  AND $pre  = "Morning";
in_array( date( "G" ), range( 12, 17 ) ) AND $pre = "Afternoon";
$work = "{$pre}s";
```